# C# Efficient way to get checked radial list option

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to reduce the amount of work / unnecessary lines and as it is now I will end up with 2000 lines.

HTML

```
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial9" value="9" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial9" class="right"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial8" value="8" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial8" class="left"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial7" value="7" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial7" class="right"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial6" value="6" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial6" class="left"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial5" value="5" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial5" class="right"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial4" value="4" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial4" class="left"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial3" value="3" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial3" class="right"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial2" value="2" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial2" class="left"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial1" value="1" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial1" class="right"></label>
    <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial0" value="0" name="test"/>
    <label for="radial0" class="left"></label>
```

Then the repetitive work to find the selected radial button begins:

```
    int selected;

    if (radial0.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial0.Value);
    }
    else if (radial1.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial1.Value);
    }
    else if (radial2.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial2.Value);
    }
    else if (radial3.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial3.Value);
    }
    else if (radial4.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial4.Value);
    }
    else if (radial5.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial5.Value);
    }
    else if (radial6.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial6.Value);
    }
    else if (radial7.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial7.Value);
    }
    else if (radial8.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial8.Value);
    }
    else if (radial9.Checked)
    {
        selected = Convert.ToInt32(radial9.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "You selected invalid";
    }
```

I mean... there should be an easier way to do this, arrays should make this way better, but I can't find a way to do it...(I need to convert the input ID to a parameter value) I would have a really neat solution could I send or make the id

```
static int getRadialChecked(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if ((name + i).Checked)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32((name + i).Value);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
    int value = getRadialChecked("radial");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped the radiobuttons in a container control

```
    <div id="radioSelections" runat="server">
        <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial9" value="9" name="test"/>
            <label for="radial9" class="right"></label>
            <input runat="server" type="radio" id="radial8" value="8" name="test"/>
            <label for="radial8" class="left"></label>
        ....
    </div>
```

Use LINQ to search the list of radio buttons to get the selected control and then get the value.

```
        var checkedButton = radioSelections.Controls.OfType<HtmlInputRadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(b=>b.Checked);
        var selected = checkedButton?.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you :)   (using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the datatype of the function (add System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;)

```
static int getRadialChecked(HtmlInputRadioButton[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (values[i].Checked)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(values[i].Value);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

-

```
HtmlInputRadioButton[] radialArray = { radial0, radial1, radial3, radial4, radial5, radial6, radial7, radial8, radial9 };
int value = getRadialChecked(radialArray);
```